# Default getter for IList<T>

Tags: c#, class, properties

I'm getting started building a C# application, and I've run into a bit of a thorn in the eye:

Most of my classes have a bunch of properties, like this:

```
private IList<Address> _addresses;
private IList<Phone> _phones;

public virtual IList<Address> Addresses
{
    get
    {
        if (_addresses == null)
            _addresses = new List<Address>();
        return _addresses;
    }
    set { _addresses = value; }
}
public virtual IList<Phone> Phones
{
    get
    {
        if (_phones == null)
            _phones = new List<Phone>();
        return _phones;
    }
    set { _phones = value; }
}
```

I was wondering, is there a way to define this kind of behavior (Specifically, the default getter) in one place, and reuse that? Should I extend `IList` somehow?

Just like I can use

```
public virtual string Temp { get; set; }
```

Instead of:

```
private string _temp;
public virtual string Temp
{
    get { return _temp; }
    set { _temp = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a static helper function while waiting for C# 6, that is how it's done in my MVVM framework of choice. I think this is a fairly general implementation, more overloads could be added to handle corner cases.

```
public static class PropertyHelper
{
    public static T Get<T, U>(ref T backingField, U initialValue = null)
        where T : class
        where U : class, T, new()
    {
        initialValue = initialValue ?? new U();
        return backingField ?? (backingField = initialValue);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    private IList<int> myVar;

    public IList<int> MyProperty
    {
        get { return PropertyHelper.Get<IList<int>, List<int>>(ref myVar); }
        set { myVar = value; }
    }

    private IList<int> myVar2;

    public IList<int> MyProperty2
    {
        get { return PropertyHelper.Get(ref myVar2, new List<int>()); }
        set { myVar2 = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, but not much shorter than the shorthand version, especially if'm going to have to `use` a class in my subclasses. Still, good to know this is possible.

Comment: yes not much shorter, but has the benefit to be implemented only in one place so it can be changed easily. You can of course make it work with primitives type too, that could be useful if you want to use an initial value differente than default(T).

Comment: I just realized all of my classes extend `Base` (`public class Address : Base`). Adding the `Get<T>` function in that class makes this very easy (and short) to implement.

Comment: Hmm, not quite going as planned: `'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Name.Space.Phone>' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Ordering.Data.Classes.Base.Get<T>(ref T)'`

Comment: Oh, seems that was because of the use of `IList` (Which I can't modify, due to the use of Fluent NHibernate)

Comment: If you are ok with declaring the backing fields as concrete classes ,you can modify my very very simplicistic solution to handle a lot of corner cases.

Comment: I tried: `IList<T> Get<T>(ref IList<T> backingField)` and `= new List<T>()`. That did the trick!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution that worked for you, i was trying to think of a more general implementation but i guess adding overloads to handle corner cases could be better.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52112/discussion-between-dtex-and-cerbrus)

Answer (score 4):

You can do with a `List<T>` exactly what you do with a `string`. The issue that you are probably running into is that in both cases the property is `null` until you assign a value, thus the `if` statement in the getter.

You won't be able to resolve this by extending `IList`.

You can initialize the backing field:

```
private IList<Thing> _things = new List<Thing>();
```

In the next version of C#, you'll actually be able to initialize an auto-property in the same way. The syntax takes a little getting used to:

```
public IList<Thing> Things { get; set; } = new List<Thing>();
```

You could also use this syntax in your getter to initialize the collection on first call to the getter:

```
get { return _things ?? (_things = new List<Thing()); }
```

Finally, you can assign the values to auto-properties in your constructor. This may be more prone to error, as the declaration and assignment have no visible connection.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest way currently to do this would be:

```
public static List<int> _list;

public static List<int> List
{
    get { return _list ?? (_list = new List<int>()); }
    set { _list = value; }
}
```

Which initializes `_list` if it's `null`, and otherwise returns the `_list` field.

Comment: This appears to be functionally identical to my original code. Not much shorter, but I like it. +1

Comment: @Cerbrus It is effectively shorthand for your original code, with the upside of having to change less per implementation as a result.

Comment: I'm going to have a look at the `??` then :)

Comment: @Cerbrus It's called the null coalescing operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could initialize your fields:

```
private IList<Address> _addresses = new List<Address>();
private IList<Phone> _phones= new List<Phone>();
```

Or set the properties in the constructor:

```
//constructor
public MyClass()
{
    Addresses = new List<Address>();
    Phones = new List<Phone>();
}
```

These aren't exactly the same the same as your code, though. In your case, if the properties are never called, they will never be initialized.

Comment: Also if the property is explicitly set to null after object is initialized, behavior will also be different. But that's the closest simple analogue i could think as well

Comment: Simple suggestion(s), but I'm not sure if it's the best one. +1 for simplicity though.

Answer (score 2):

In the uppcoming C# 6 you can do the following:

```
public virtual IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; } = new List<Address>(); 
public virtual IList<Phone> Phones { get; set; } = new List<Phone>();
```

for now you could use auto-properties and a default contructor to make it shorter:

```
public virtual IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }; 
public virtual IList<Phone> Phones { get; set; };

public CLASS()
{
    Addresses = new List<Address>();
    Phones = new List<Phone>()
}
```

**NOTE:** Both solutions will initialize the lists immediatly and not on first access. If that is not wanted I think you can use PostSharp for such stuff.

> Should I extend IList somehow?

This would not help, as in case of a "non initialized field" your custom implementation would not even be "there yet".

Comment: I'd like to maintain the "Initialize on first access" functionality. And "Duh" on your answer about extending `IList`. Why didn't I think of that :P